# Can I login to Stack Overflow with 2 Google accounts?

Tags: discussion, openid

I have 2 Google accounts I would like to be able to log into Stack Overflow with.
One personal, and one is work.
There are many things that I need to keep separated along those lines.
But I would prefer to keep all of my Stack Overflow questions with one account.

Is there a way I can associate both of my Google accounts with one Stack Overflow account?

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow offers an option to merge to accounts created by same person.https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts Read the details on the above link and follow it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this.

Login via "Stack Exchange" (instead of "Log in via Google")
Then under your account go to my logins.
Then choose to add a Google login, and use your alternate Google credentials.

Now both Google credentials will login to the same account.